# css grid how to make a 3 column layout with a massive column to the left and 2 columns to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image: image of a grid layout]

hello I'm trying replicate this image above with CSS grid its almost done, but I'm running into a issue with the main content section where you see "Your Projects" "Announcements" "Trending". I've been trying to arrange the content in a way where "your projects" take us a large portion of space in the grid. While "Announcements" and "Trending" are to the right of it. I'm trying to increase the rows of each section "your projects" and "Announcements" would increase, but "trending" would just be a small box uneven in size with "Announcements" how can I fix this?

html

```
                <div class="main-content-grid-container">
                <div class="projects-container main-content-grid">
                    <h1>projects</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="announcements-container main-content-grid">
                    <h1>announcements</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="trending-container main-content-grid">
                    <h1>trending</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
.main-content-container{
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.main-content-grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 10fr 1fr;
    
}

.projects-container{

}

.announcements-container{
}

.trending-container{
    grid-area: 2/3/2/2;
}

.main-content-grid{
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

Comment: Use 2 grids. One for the sidebar and the content area, then inside the content area another 2 for the content itself.

Comment: Can you post a modified image that shows what you *want* it to look like, ideally with indications of sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background: blue;
}

.mainContent {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.rightContent {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-box {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-box .inner {
    padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="mainContent">
      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="inner">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rightContent">
      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="inner">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Then create 2 new columns:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background: blue;
}

.mainContent {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.rightContent {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-box {
    background: white;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    /*Only for demostration*/
    height: 300px;
}

.column {
  background: green;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="mainContent">
      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="column" style="float: left;">
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="float: right;">
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rightContent">
      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="inner">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve, to have the trending stay within the right-hand column underneath announcements, surround both announcements and trending in a div of their own:

```
<div class="main-content-grid-container">
    <div class="projects-container main-content-grid">
        <h1>projects</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="announcements-container main-content-grid">
            <h1>announcements</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="trending-container main-content-grid">
            <h1>trending</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then whatever spacing and styling you wish to apply to both announcements and trending, you can apply to that new div.